# Duplicate entry error while creating sessions in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, session

I have been facing an issue frequently with Laravel sessions using the database driver.

> production.ERROR: PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '4t343hgjaddsdfGBjsdmS5iAIr0r36r484gaduaD' for key
>   'sessions_id_unique' in /var/app/current/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:91

I am using Laravel 5.3 and MySQL 5.6.

Because of this error, Laravel application is logging the user out.

I have attached the code snippet

```
public function takeCall(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $user = Employee::where('token', $input['token'])->first();
    if (!$user) {
        return response()->view('errors.error_page');
    }
    Auth::login($user);
    return redirect('take-call');
}
```

Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Sounds like it should be doing an `UPDATE` and not an `INSERT`

Comment: a code snippet will be appreciated to help you

Comment: @GhostWorker : I have added the code snippet in question.

Comment: @delboy1978uk : Can i get any extra details?

Comment: the user u are retrieving from here does not implement AuthenticatableContract. It would be nice if there is a mapping between the EMployee table and the User table

Comment: @Ghost Worker : AuthenticatableContract is implemented on Employee model.

Comment: which config/auth.php and check the model in the provider to be sure you have Employee model there

Comment: once try to clear your cache and config. Hope your issue resolve by this.

Comment: @all, Thanks for the response. I am using Laravel 5.3.29. Laravel is fixed this issue in 5.3.30 version. Now I have updated the version to 5.3.30. Now it is working fine.